# Data Flow Task Vs Insert

Tags: sql, ssis

I am busy creating a ssis package and would like to ask a simple question. I have a step where I populate two different tables with the same contracts. There are a few million rows that need to be populated. What is the best method to do this?...the source table is on the same server as the two destination tables, so should I do two separate normal insert statements or two data flow tasks or one data flow task with a multicast transformation? I have tested all three ways, with a portion of the data and they all take about the same time. Also which method would have the least impact on the transaction log?...I am still beginner in ssis and have tried searching for answers but cannot find a simple answer. Thanking you in advance.

Comment: I would prefer 2 data flows in case you need to change the transformations for one of the 2 paths later. This is not related to performance but more on ease of maintenance.

Comment: You might find it faster to run a INSERT/SELECT in an execute SQL statement.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. ElectricLlama I someone told before that an insert/select statement is better performance wise, but does it use less space on the transaction log? I read somewhere that data flow tasks break up the records and inserts 10k rows at time. Wouldn't this have less impact on transaction log, because there are a lot of ssis processes running at once.

Comment: Yes SSIS does it in batches in its own memory buffers but at the target end it still commits in one big batch if that's what you tell it to do. You can also write an INSERT/SELECT that commits in smaller batches if there is a transaction log issue. Yes unfortunately there is no simple answer, you need to weigh all of your options up, including what method will be easier for you to maintain.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I will look into INSERT/SELECT that uses smaller batches.